# racket to-string function for integer and string

Tags: racket

Need to write a `to-string` function that accepts integer and string.

```
(to-string 3) ; -> "3"
(to-string "hello") ; -> "\"hello\""
(to-string "hel\"lo") ; -> "\"hel\\\"lo\""
```

I managed to do so with:

```
(define (to-string x)
  (define o (open-output-string))
  (write x o)
  (define str (get-output-string o))
  (get-output-bytes o #t)
  str
  )
(to-string 3)
(to-string "hello")
(to-string "hel\"lo")
```

However, the `get-output-bytes` reseting is not very readable. What's the idiomatic Racket way of doing it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does the `~v` function or the `~s` function from [`racket/format`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28part._format%29) work for you?

```
> (~v 3)
"3"
> (~v "hello")
"\"hello\""
> (~v "hel\"lo")
"\"hel\\\"lo\""
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if `~v` and `~s` functions still require `racket/format` library for the `#lang racket`, but you can use `format` function (see more [details](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html?q=format#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._format%29%29)) that works even for the `racket/base`

```
#lang racket/base
(format "~v" 3)
(format "~v" "hello")
(format "~v" "hel\"lo")
```

That gives you exactly what you need:

```
"3"
"\"hello\""
"\"hel\\\"lo\""
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. FYI, `~v` works ok with bare `#lang racket`, http://docs.racket-lang.org/search/index.html?q=~v Still, I could use `format` if I want to cut down the dependency. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Using format works, but there are problems. there's no guarantee that what you've been passed is actually a string or an integer. It could be a list or a hash or whatever.

Here's a function to convert an integer or string to a string and raise a contract violation if you tried to do something unexpected like pass in a hash.

You could easily extend this to allow any number by changing the `integer?` to `number?` in the contract.

```lisp
#lang racket

(define/contract (int-or-string->string var)
  (-> (or/c string? integer?) string?)
  (if (string? var)
      var
      (number->string var))
     
  )
```